# How to get a integer from a text file, add to it and then put it back into the file

Tags: python

Ok this may seem simple but im having alot of problems with it and was wondering how to do it!

Ok so in my text file i have one line with a number. Lets say 50. This is a number that every time i complete a action i want to add 1 to it. Storing it in a text file means that i can restart the program and it keep the number.

i have been doing it like this:

```
num_list_location = os.path.join(postnumber_save, "postnumber.txt")
postnum = open(num_list_location, 'a+').read()
comment = 'Post No.: ' + postnum
#Do some thing with code
newpostnum = int(postnum) += 1 #This is what gives the error
open(num_list_location, 'a+').write(str(newpostnum))
```

Then i want it to write over with the newpostnum and continue with the program!

So it does not work and just throughs back errors, so i was wondering what would be the best way to do what i have asked! Thanks

EDIT

To fix my problem thanks to Steven, my problem was the 'a+' if you change it to 'r' for the read one and 'w' for the write one then it works

```
postnum = open(num_list_location, 'r').read()
open(num_list_location, 'w').write(str(newpostnum))
```

Another thing that needed changed is the:

```
newpostnum = int(postnum) += 1
```

to

```
newpostnum = int(postnum) + 1
```

And it now works fine!

Comment: It's `+=` not `=+`. Also, you can't increment and assign on the same line.

Comment: @MorganThrapp:  Here I think he want's just `+`.  If he made it `+=` he would be assigning to the result of `int(postnum)`, which would also be an error.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski That would make sense.

Comment: @MorganThrapp i ment += i was silly when coping it out, i changed it to a + but it throughs back errors: "newpostnum = int(file) + 1
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "

Comment: Note that opening your file `'a+'` for writing will result in the new number being appended to the file.  It won't replace the existing number.  If the file contains "50" and you open with `'a+'` and you write to file your file will now contain "5051".

Comment: Then edit that in your post, and add the actual error.

Comment: @Jonese1234:  You wrote in your comment `int(file) + 1`.  Surely you meant to write `int(postnum) + 1`, no?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski why thank you, that fixed it! I changed the read one to r and the write one to w!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix my problem thanks to Steven, my problem was the 'a+' if you change it to 'r' for the read one and 'w' for the write one then it works

```
postnum = open(num_list_location, 'r').read()
open(num_list_location, 'w').write(str(newpostnum))
```

Another thing that needed changed is the:

```
newpostnum = int(postnum) += 1
```

to

```
newpostnum = int(postnum) + 1
```

And it now works fine!